# knockout.js using keywords "this" and "that"

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js, this, viewmodel

I am new and learning knockout libraries. I have two questions.

1) What is the difference between the terms this and that.
2) What does this.view and that.view mean.

I am mainly asking this question because I am using highcharts and renderTo is set to that.view, when I assign it to a div tag it works well upon first time load, if that chart needs to be loaded again, it div tag value doesn't display the chart. However it displays it everytime with this.view.

```
 this.chartHeight = this.view.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().height
 this.chart = {
                renderTo:    that.view, //'chart-container',
                     };
```

So while understanding this, I want to know, what the difference is between this.view and that.view.

Thanks

Comment: "this" is a language keyword with special meaning. "that" is just an ordinary variable like any other, and has whatever value it was assigned.

Comment: it's not possible to tell you what 'that' refers to, without seeing the rest of your code; specifically the part where 'that' was defined. We would also need to see where 'view' was defined. All we can tell you is the meaning of 'this': https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Btw, if you are thinking that 'that' has some special meaning in Knockout, that's not true.

Comment: seems like `that` is a child view of the parent `this` view...

Comment: Thanks much. All those commends answered that question. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [each function in JavaScript is given its own `this` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), it's common to create a local variable to hold the `this` value for embedded functions to access through the closure. Often this variable is called `self` or sometimes `that` or `_this`, but it can really be any legal variable name. In ES6, it's preferable to use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: If I answered your question, please accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: Sorry this is my first question here on stack overflow. How do I accept answers and say it's done and close this?